# Keep getting "EOFError: Ran out of input" error

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, transformer-model, pytorch-lightning

So basicly i am trying to use a transformer model to classify ecg heartbeats. I got error after running the following script:

```
# Import Necessary Dependencies

import os
import copy
import pandas as pd
import math


# Pytorch
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.utils.data.dataset import Dataset
from torch.utils.data.dataloader import DataLoader
from torch.optim import Adam

# Pytorch Lightning
from pytorch_lightning import LightningModule, LightningDataModule
from pytorch_lightning import Trainer
from pytorch_lightning.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint


# Torchmetric for computing accuracy
from torchmetrics.functional import accuracy

# Plotting
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Dataset

def load_list(root, filename):
    filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)
    output = pd.read_csv(filepath, header=None)
    return output

class MITBIHArrhythmia(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, root, subset=None):
        assert subset is None or subset in ["training", "validation", "testing"], (
            "When `subset` not None, it must take a value from " + "{'training', 'validation', 'testing'}."
        )
        self.root = root
        file_dict = {
            "training": "mitbih_train.csv",
            "validation": "mitbih_test.csv",
            "testing": "mitbih_test.csv"
        }
        self._walker = load_list(self.root, file_dict[subset])
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._walker)
    def __getitem__(self, n:int):
        row = self._walker.loc[n, :].values.tolist()
        label = row.pop()
        return row, label

## Data Visualization

ds = MITBIHArrhythmia("C:/Users/Samet/Desktop/ECG", "training")

CLASSES_DICT = {
    0: "Normal beat (N)",
    1: "Supraventricular premature beat (S)",
    2: "Premature ventricular contraction (V)",
    3: "Fusion of ventricular and normal beat (F)",
    4: "Unclassifiable beat (Q)"
}
class_to_dsindx = {0:0, 1:72471, 2:74694, 3:80482, 4:81123}
# 0 starts at index 0, 1 starts at index 72471, 2 starts at index 74694
# 3 starts at index 80482, 4 starts at index 81123

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 3, figsize=(20, 10))

for cat, value in CLASSES_DICT.items():
    ax = axes[int(cat/3), cat%3]
    for j in range(5):
        indx = class_to_dsindx[cat]
        ax.plot(ds[indx+j][0])
    ax.set(title=f"1-beat ECG for {CLASSES_DICT[cat]}")
    ax.set(ylabel="Amplitude")
    ax.set(xlabel="Time (ms)")
plt.show()

# Transformer Model
#The Transformer used below is a modified version of the original transformer. Since the application need not translation, the decoder block was completely removed. The positional embeddings were also removed since adding this layer reduces accuracy (I don't know why). The Positional Feed Forward was also changed to a simple Feed Forward Network. A fully connected was attached to the end of the network for classition. A softmax layer was not added since we used we used CrossEntropyLoss() for calculating the loss.

#Essentially, our model was composed of
#Encoder block (N duplicates) -> Fully Connected Network (nn.Linear)

#The Encoder block is composed of two SublayerConnections (Attention and Feed-Forward Network).
#The codes below were copied from http://nlp.seas.harvard.edu/annotated-transformer/ (GitHub: https://github.com/harvardnlp/annotated-transformer/).

def clones(module, N):
    "Produce N identical layers."
    return nn.ModuleList([copy.deepcopy(module) for _ in range(N)])


#### ATTENTION
def attention(query, key, value, mask=None, dropout=None):
    "Compute 'Scaled Dot Product Attention'"
    d_k = query.size(-1)
    scores = torch.matmul(query, key.transpose(-2, -1)) / math.sqrt(d_k)
    if mask is not None:
        scores = scores.masked_fill(mask == 0, -1e9)
    p_attn = scores.softmax(dim=-1)
    if dropout is not None:
        p_attn = dropout(p_attn)
    return torch.matmul(p_attn, value), p_attn

class MultiHeadedAttention(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, h, d_model, dropout=0.0):
        "Take in model size and number of heads."
        super(MultiHeadedAttention, self).__init__()
        assert d_model % h == 0
        # We assume d_v always equals d_k
        self.d_k = d_model // h
        self.h = h
        self.linears = clones(nn.Linear(d_model, d_model), 4)
        self.attn = None
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(p=dropout)

    def forward(self, query, key, value, mask=None):
        if mask is not None:
            mask = mask.unsqueeze(1) # Same mask applied to all h heads.

        # 1) Do all the linear projections in batch from d_model => h x d_k
        query, key, value = [
            lin(x).view( -1, self.h, self.d_k).transpose(1, 2)
            for lin, x in zip(self.linears, (query, key, value))
        ]

        # 2) Apply attention on all the projected vectors in batch.
        x, self.attn = attention(query, key, value, mask=mask, dropout=self.dropout)

        # 3) "Concat" using a view and apply a final linear.
        x = (x.transpose(1, 2).contiguous().view( -1, self.h * self.d_k))
        
        del query
        del key
        del value
        out = self.linears[-1](x)
        return out

## BLOCKING
class LayerNorm(nn.Module):
    "Construct a layernorm module."
    def __init__(self, features, eps=1e-6):
        super().__init__()
        self.a_2 = nn.Parameter(torch.ones(features))
        self.b_2 = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(features))
        self.eps = eps
    
    def forward(self, x):
        mean = x.mean(-1, keepdim=True)
        std = x.std(-1, keepdim=True)
        return self.a_2 * (x - mean) / (std + self.eps) + self.b_2

class SublayerConnection(nn.Module):
    "A residual connection followed by a layer norm."
    def __init__(self, size, dropout):
        super().__init__()
        self.norm = LayerNorm(size)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)
    
    def forward(self, x, sublayer):
        "Apply residual connection to any sublayer with the same size."
        return x + self.dropout(sublayer(self.norm(x)))

class EncoderBlock(nn.Module):
    "Encoder is made up of self-attn and feed forward"
    def __init__(self, size, self_attn, feed_forward, dropout):
        super().__init__()
        self.self_attn = self_attn
        self.feed_forward = feed_forward
        self.sublayer = clones(SublayerConnection(size, dropout), 2)
        self.size = size

    def forward(self, x, mask):
        "Follow Figure 1 (left) for connections."
        x = self.sublayer[0](x, lambda x: self.self_attn(x, x, x, mask))
        x = self.sublayer[1](x, self.feed_forward)
        return x

class Encoder(nn.Module):
    "Core encoder is a stack of N layers"
    def __init__(self, layer, N):
        super(Encoder, self).__init__()
        self.layers = clones(layer, N)
        self.norm = LayerNorm(layer.size)

    def forward(self, x, mask=None):
        "Pass the input (and mask) through each layer in turn."
        for layer in self.layers:
            x = layer(x, mask)
        return self.norm(x)

class FeedForward(nn.Module):
    "Construct a FeedForward network with one hidden layer"
    def __init__(self, d_model, d_ff, dropout=0.1):
        super().__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(d_model, d_ff)
        self.act = nn.GELU()
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(d_ff, d_model)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = self.act(x)
        x = self.dropout(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return x

class Transformer(nn.Module):
    "Transformer Model"
    def __init__(self, input_size, num_classes, num_heads=8, N=6, d_ff=256, dropout=0.0):
        super().__init__()
        c = copy.deepcopy
        attn = MultiHeadedAttention(num_heads, input_size)
        ff = FeedForward(input_size, d_ff, dropout)
        self.encoder = Encoder(EncoderBlock(input_size, c(attn), c(ff), dropout), N)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(input_size, num_classes)
    
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.encoder(x)
        x = self.fc(x)
        return x

# Pytorch Ligthning Modules

class LitMITBIH(LightningDataModule):
    def __init__(self, root, batch_size, num_workers, length=200):
        super().__init__()
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.num_workers = num_workers
        self.path = root
        self.length = length
    
    def prepare_data(self):
        self.train_dataset = MITBIHArrhythmia(self.path, "training")
        self.val_dataset = MITBIHArrhythmia(self.path, "validation")
        self.test_dataset = MITBIHArrhythmia(self.path, "testing")
    
    def setup(self, stage=None):
        self.prepare_data()

    def train_dataloader(self):
        return DataLoader(
            self.train_dataset,
            batch_size=self.batch_size,
            num_workers=self.num_workers,
            shuffle=True,
            pin_memory=True,
            collate_fn=self.collate_fn
        )
    
    def val_dataloader(self):
        return DataLoader(
            self.val_dataset,
            batch_size=self.batch_size,
            num_workers=self.num_workers,
            shuffle=False, 
            pin_memory=True,
            collate_fn=self.collate_fn
        )
    
    def test_dataloader(self):
        return DataLoader(
            self.test_dataset,
            batch_size=self.batch_size,
            num_workers=self.num_workers,
            shuffle=False, 
            pin_memory=True,
            collate_fn=self.collate_fn
        )

    def collate_fn(self, batch):
        labels = []
        heartbeats = []
        for sample in batch:
            waveform, label = sample
            if len(waveform) < self.length:
                padsize = self.length - len(waveform)
                waveform += [0]*padsize

            labels.append(torch.tensor(label).type(torch.int64))
            heartbeats.append(torch.tensor(waveform))

        labels = torch.stack(labels)
        heartbeats = torch.stack(heartbeats)
        return heartbeats, labels

class LitTransformer(LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, input_size, num_classes, num_heads, depth, max_epochs, lr,  dropout=0.1, d_ff=256):
        super().__init__()
        self.save_hyperparameters()
        self.model = Transformer(input_size, num_classes, num_heads, depth, d_ff, dropout)
        self.loss = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
        self.reset_parameters()

    def reset_parameters(self):
        for p in self.model.parameters():
            if p.dim() > 1:
                nn.init.xavier_uniform_(p)
    
    def forward(self, x):
        return self.model(x)

    def configure_optimizers(self):
        optimizer = Adam(self.parameters(), lr=self.hparams.lr)
        # scheduler = CosineAnnealingLR(optimizer, T_max=self.hparams.max_epochs)
        return optimizer #[optimizer], [scheduler]
    
    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        wavs, labels = batch
        preds = self(wavs)
        loss = self.loss(preds, labels)
        self.log('train_loss', loss)
        return {"loss": loss}
    
    def training_epoch_end(self, outputs):
        avg_loss = torch.stack([x["loss"] for x in outputs]).mean()
        self.log("train_loss", avg_loss, on_epoch=True)
    
    def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        return self.test_step(batch, batch_idx)

    def validation_epoch_end(self, outputs):
        return self.test_epoch_end(outputs)
    
    def test_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        wavs, labels = batch
        preds = self(wavs)
        loss = self.loss(preds, labels)
        acc = accuracy(preds, labels) * 100.
        return {"preds": preds, 'test_loss': loss, 'test_acc': acc}

    def test_epoch_end(self, outputs):
        avg_loss = torch.stack([x['test_loss'] for x in outputs]).mean()
        avg_acc = torch.stack([x['test_acc'] for x in outputs]).mean()
        self.log("test_loss", avg_loss, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True)
        self.log("test_acc", avg_acc, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True)

# TRAINING

path = "C:/Users/Samet/Desktop/ECG"
input_size = 200
batch_size = 128
num_workers = 20
lr = 1e-4
max_epochs = 20
num_heads = 5
depth = 6
num_classes = 5
dropout = 0.0

datamodule = LitMITBIH(path, batch_size, num_workers, length=input_size)
datamodule.setup()

model = LitTransformer(input_size, num_classes, num_heads, depth, max_epochs, lr, dropout)
print(model)



save_path = "C:/Users/Samet/Desktop/ECG/working"
ckpt_name = "ecg-transformer"
model_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(
    dirpath=os.path.join(save_path, "checkpoints"),
    filename=ckpt_name,
    save_top_k=1,
    verbose=True,
    monitor='test_acc',
    mode='max',
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    trainer = Trainer(accelerator="gpu", devices=1,
                    max_epochs=max_epochs,
                    logger=None,
                    callbacks=[model_checkpoint]
                )
    trainer.fit(model, datamodule=datamodule)

# Testing
model = model.load_from_checkpoint(
    os.path.join(save_path, "checkpoints", ckpt_name+".ckpt")
)

trainer.test(model, datamodule=datamodule)
```

```
C:\Users\Samet\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\callbacks\model_checkpoint.py:604: UserWarning: Checkpoint directory C:\Users\Samet\Desktop\ECG\working\checkpoints exists and is not empty.
  rank_zero_warn(f"Checkpoint directory {dirpath} exists and is not empty.")

EOFError: Ran out of input
```

First i was getting "An attempt has been made to start a new process before the current process has finished its bootstrapping phase." error so i put the "if _*name*_ == '_*main*_':" line now i get Ran out of input error. I dont know what to do next.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

It works with `num_workers = 0` and `accelerator="cpu"`.